# Rails pass id in selection instead of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select form:

```
<%= f.select :business_name,  options_for_select(Client.uniq.pluck(:business_name)),{:include_blank => false},{:multiple=>true} %>
```

It picks out the **distinct** `business_name` and renders them in a selection box. I need the form to send the relevant `business_id` when a `business_name` is selected instead of sending the name string.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

options_for_select takes an array of arrays. Ideally if you want the name and value on the html select option to be different you pass in those pairs as [name, value].  By using pluck to grab only the business name you're passing in [name]--no value to put into the option tag.

change your code to use:

```
...options_for_select(Client.uniq.pluck(:business_name, :id))...>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
options_for_select(Client.uniq(:business_name).collect{ |c| [c. business_name, c.id] })
```

So you would return all unique values on business name and the collect with name-value pair for select